# Selenium + Python: next button through click()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I don't understand why when I go to this page

> https://www.ryanair.com/it/it/voli-low-cost/?from=BGY&out-from-date=2018-09-01&out-to-date=2018-09-30&budget=60&trip-length-from=1&trip-length-to=3

or whatever page from that website, Selenium doesn't allow me on the script to run the next page button with the code:

```
next_page = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/farefinder-widget/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/core-pagination/div/div[2]/a')
next_page.click()
```

On the HTML code:

```
<a ng-class="{'disabled': $ctrl.isLastPage($ctrl.currentPageIndex)}" ng-click="$ctrl.handleNextClick()" class="core-link"><span class="nav-label">Successivo</span><core-icon icon-id="glyphs.chevron-right" class="icon-22 fill-ryanair-bright-blue"><div><svg tabindex="-1" focusable="false" role="img"><use xlink:href="/it/it/voli-low-cost/?from=BGY&amp;out-from-date=2018-09-01&amp;out-to-date=2018-09-30&amp;budget=60&amp;trip-length-from=1&amp;trip-length-to=3#glyphs.chevron-right" ng-href="/it/it/voli-low-cost/?from=BGY&amp;out-from-date=2018-09-01&amp;out-to-date=2018-09-30&amp;budget=60&amp;trip-length-from=1&amp;trip-length-to=3#glyphs.chevron-right"></use></svg></div></core-icon></a>
```

Whereas If I write it on the shell, oddly enough it does work, with the same exact lines. I've also tried to give it some seconds with `time.sleep`, but nothing happened.

Comment: you want to click on anchor tag which you have shared with us ? or after clicking on click button , you are not able to interact with page which comes next ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You need to scroll the desired element into view before you try to click it.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination appears to be disabled for this element, i.e. `<a ng-class="{'disabled': $ctrl.isLastPage....`. It works for me if I click on the parent div, like so:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".next.vertical-center").click()
```

Or, if you want use your xpath, you just need to remove the last 'a':

```
next_step = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/farefinder-widget/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/core-pagination/div/div[2]')
```

For readability, I recommend the CSS selector.

**EDIT:** You are probably getting an exception because the element is not visible. Just need to scroll the element into view.

```
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".next.vertical-center")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.click()
```